# Split a data frame by particular variables that are within the same column

Tags: r

I have data table organized into columns "color" and "direction". In the "color" column, there are only 2 different variables, red and white.

I'm super new with working with R and was wondering how to split this data table into 2 separate data tables, one with only the data associated with red and another set with data only associated with white.

Comment: This will give you subset of red colour: `myRed <- mydata[ mydata$color == "red", ]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want match "red" exactly, you can use

```
myRed <- mydata[ mydata$color == "red", ] 
mywhite <- mydata[ mydata$color == "white", ]
```

or, if you want to partially match, you can use `?grepl` which returns a logical index for subsetting:

```
myRed = mydata[ grepl("red", tolower(mydata$color)),]
mywhite = mydata[ !grepl("red", tolower(mydata$color)),]
```

Comment: We can do it without stringr also